# Undefined reference errors linking a dll in QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, dll, mingw

I have built a simple dll using g++ under mingw:
We have an include file:

```
#ifndef __TESTDLL_H
#define __TESTDLL_H

class sineCalculator
{
    double n;
public:
    sineCalculator();
    sineCalculator(double);
    double sine();
    void setAngle(double);
};

#endif
```

Then an implementation cpp:

```
#include <testdll.h>
#include <math.h>

sineCalculator::sineCalculator()
{
    n = 0;
}

sineCalculator::sineCalculator(double x)
{
    n = x;
}

double sineCalculator::sine()
{
    return sin(n);
}

void sineCalculator::setAngle(double x)
{
    n = x;
}
```

This I have compiled as a dll.producing both a .dll file and .a import library with the names visaTest.dll and libvisaTest.a

I can write a small program and link to this dll successfully just using the command line - no Qt just g++. I can create objects and run the methods all fine.

However, I now want to add this library to a Qt application within QtCreator. I have followed the advice of several questions and added these lines to my .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/msys64/home/hoyla/libs/
INCLUDEPATH +=C:/msys64/home/hoyla/includes/
DEPENDPATH +=C:/msys64/home/hoyla/libs/

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -LC:/msys64/home/hoyla/libs/ -lvisaTest
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release):  LIBS += -LC:/msys64/home/hoyla/libs/ -lvisaTest
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../libs/ -lvisaTest
```

Although I use some absolute paths here I have also tried with relative paths. However, I keep getting undefined reference errors to my dll functions when building the Qt file. I would point out that the paths point to the location of my .a import library, the .dll itself is within the system path. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Mea Culpa! It seems I had compiled my library under 64-bit MinGW but Qt Creator was defaulting to the 32-bit toolchain. One would have thought that the linker might have been able to determine that was the error and generate a more useful error message but there we go. Lesson learned - make sure you're using the tools you think you're using.